# How to move popup for a point to anchor/position on specific part of screen?

Tags: css, popup, mapbox

Hi,

Here is my website www.livehazards.com. I am trying to move the popup box associated with each earthquake to the bottom right hand of the screen.

Here is the code associated with the popupbox

```
 .mapboxgl-popup-content {padding:10px; background:rgba(54, 69, 79, 0.8); color:#fff; pointer-events:none;}

 var feature = features[0];
var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup()
    .setLngLat (feature.geometry.coordinates)
    .setHTML ('Magnitude = <b> '+ feature.properties.mag + '</b>,' + ' Location = <b>' + feature.properties.place + '</b>,' + ' Time: <b> ' + expressTime(feature.properties.time)[0]+' '+expressTime(feature.properties.time)[1]+' ago </b>'+ '  Felt by:<b> ' + Feltby(feature.properties.felt)+ '</b>').addTo(map);
```

});

...I can move the popup box in relation to the point but cannot move the popupbox to a specific area and anchor it there (Even with position:absolute?)

```
.mapboxgl-popup-content {
right:100px;
bottom:100px;
position:absolute;
  }
```

Does anyone know how to do this thanks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `position:fixed` to set it relative to the viewport (*although in your case that the container is full size you can use `position:absolute`*), and also add `transform:none!important` to disable the inline style applied by the library.

```
.mapboxgl-map .mapboxgl-popup{
    right:100px;
    bottom:100px;
    top:auto;
    left:auto;
    position:fixed;
    transform:none !important;
}
.mapboxgl-map .mapboxgl-popup-tip{display:none;}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply but it did not work. It would still place the popup up in relation to the click.....but I need the popups from every click to be in the bottom right hand of the screen

Comment: @CharlesHarrison my error. You need to target the `.mapboxgl-popup` and not the `.mapboxgl-popup-content`. You should also hide the `.mapboxgl-popup-tip` element now since it is not helpful. updated answer

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that kind of worked......but now its just placing the popup right at the top of the page? Instead of in the bottom right hand corner. any ideas?

Comment: @CharlesHarrison yes. Our rules are inserted before the one from the library and so when setting the same properties the later ones prevail. Just make the rules more specific. (*updated answer*)